# Arduino Sensor Values to Raspberry Pi using NRF24

Tags: arduino-uno, c, nrf24l01+, python, raspberrypi

Im trying to send temperature sensor data through NRF24L01 to Raspberry Pi and read it in Raspberry Pi using python. But the temperature sensor data comes to the Raspberry Pi as letters, which I found out is in Ascii values. Im not sure how to display the actual readings from the Arduino to the Raspberry Pi

Here is the Arduino code:

```
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include "printf.h"
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2

OneWire oneWire (ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

RF24 radio(9, 10);

void setup(void) {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  sensors.begin();
  radio.begin() ;
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX) ;
  radio.setChannel(0x76) ;
  radio.openWritingPipe(0xF0F0F0F0E1LL) ;
  radio.enableDynamicPayloads() ;
  radio.powerUp() ;
}

void loop(void) {
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  float temperature = sensors.getTempFByIndex(0);
  radio.write(&temperature, sizeof(float));
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print(sensors.getTempFByIndex(0));
}
```

Here is the code for Raspberry Pi in Python

```
from lib_nrf24 import NRF24
import time
import spidev

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
pipes = [[0xE8, 0xE8, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1], [0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1]]

radio = NRF24(GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
radio.begin(0, 17)

radio.setPayloadSize(32)
radio.setChannel(0x76)
radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_1MBPS)
radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MIN)

radio.setAutoAck(True)
radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
radio.enableAckPayload()

radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[1])
radio.printDetails()
radio.startListening()

while True:

    while not radio.available(0):
        time.sleep(1/100)

    receivedMessage = []
    radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
    print("Received: {}".format(receivedMessage))

    print("Translating...")
    string = ""

    for n in receivedMessage:
        if (n >= 32 and n <= 126):
            string += chr(n)
    print("Our received message decodes to: {}".format(string))
```

I want to get the temperature value in numbers instead of letters. Instead of like this:

Translating ... Our received message decodes to: N

Comment: why are you asking a python question at an arduino site? ... arduino does not run python

Comment: Im trying to see if there is a way to modify the Arduino's code to get the sensor values as a string so that it can be read by rpi